# Why does NASM system call number perform 2 different operations despite specifying the same call number

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

I have the following 'hello world' code written in NASM x86_64 assembly:

```
section .data
    msg     db "Hello World", 0xa
    msg_L   equ $-msg

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov     eax, 4      ; sys_write call
    mov     ebx, 1      ; stdout
    mov     ecx, msg
    mov     edx, msg_L
    int     0x80        ; call kernel

    mov     eax, 1      ; sys_exit call
    int     0x80        ; call kernel
```

In the first 'function' under the `_start:` section, `mov ebx, 1` is used to specify the standard output for printing. Later, after the first kernel call, `mov eax, 1` is used to specify the `sys_exit` system call. I don't understand how specifying the same system call number yields 2 different results when the kernel is called. [This NASM tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm) specifies 1 as the system call number for `sys_exit`, yet the program does not exit after the first use of that number, and uses it for `stdout` instead. Can someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: You're mixing eax and ebx.  Eax specifies what function to perform.  Other registers (like ebx) specify parameters.

Comment: It's a coincidence that `__NR_exit == STDOUT_FILENO`.  The first system call could be written in C as `write(__NR_exit == STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg))` if you wanted to be weird about it.  (Because a true `==` evaluates to an integer `1` which is also the same as both those constants.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the same system call number.

`eax`, not `ebx`, is used to specify system call numbers.

`mov ebx, 1` sets the value of `ebx` and doesn't set the value of `eax`.

The system call number is set to `4` via `mov eax, 4` when using the standard output set by `mov ebx, 1`.

Comment: And specifically, `ebx` holds the first arg, which for `write` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is `int fd` so that's `mov ebx, STDOUT_FILENO`.  Just a coincidence that it's the same number as `__NR_exit`.